# distribution of areas of random closed loops on a lattice

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a planar square lattice, i.e. ${Z}^2$. I consider the set of the closed paths on this lattice, starting and ending at some fixed base point (imposing a base point is just to avoid considering paths that are identical up to a translation). More specifically, I am interested in the subset of these closed paths that make $2n_1$ steps in the $\pm x$ directions, and $2n_2$ steps in the $\pm y$ directions. Let us call it $\Gamma_{n_1,n_2}$.

Now consider the algebraic area $Area(\gamma)$ of a closed path $\gamma\in\Gamma_{n_1,n_2}$. By algebraic, I mean that the contribution of each lattice plaquette to the area is weighted by the winding number of the path around that plaquette.

Are the moments $\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{n_1,n_2}}(Area(\gamma))^k$   known as a function of $n_1,n_2$ and $k$?  Obviously, the odd moments are zero. Also I believe the asymptotic behavior of the moments for large $n_1,n_2$ is probably easier to obtain. But I am wondering about whether an exact  formula is known for finite $n_1,n_2$.

Comment: You need to specify a probability distribution on the closed paths for this to make sense.  Also, do you intend to include only simple closed paths (i.e. non-self-intersecting)?

Comment: At each node of the lattice, the hopping probability is uniform: $1/4$ for each possible direction. All the paths are included, in particular they are not required to be self-avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in [Epelbaum et al., Ann.Inst.H.Poincare D 3 (2016) 4, 381](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=2308-5827&vol=3&iss=4&rank=2):
$$\sum_{\gamma\in{\Gamma}_{n_1,n_2}}
\left({\rm Area}\,(\gamma)\right)^{2l}
=\frac{(2(n_1+n_2))!}{n_1!^2n_2!^2}\;{\cal P}_{2l}(n_1,n_2),
$$
where ${\cal P}_{2l}$ is a symmetric polynomial in $n_1,n_2$ of degree
$2l$. The first four of these polynomials read
$${\cal P}_0(n_1,n_2)=1$$
$${\cal P}_2(n_1,n_2)=\frac{n_1n_2}{3}$$
$${\cal P}_4(n_1,n_2)=\frac{n_1 n_2\big({7 n_1n_2}
\!-\!({n_1\!+\!n_2})
\big)}{15}$$
$${\cal P}_6(n_1,n_2)=\frac{n_1 n_2}{21}\big(31 (n_1n_2)^2
-15(n_1n_2)(n_1\!+\!n_2)
+2(n_1+n_2)^2
-({n_1+n_2})
\big)$$
Explicit formulas up to ${\cal P}_{12}$ are given in the above reference. A semi-explicit formula exists for this polynomial, but its evaluation cost becomes prohibitive for large moments.